# Microsoft Graph API: A question about IDriveItemCollectionPage

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I look at the docs regarding this and struggling about with how IDriveItemCollectionPage works.

I am currently doing the following, trying to list all children DriveItems of the root drive of a site given its Drive Id with the Java SDK

```
    public ArrayList<DriveItem> getDriveItemChildrenFoldersOfRootDrive(String rootDriveId){
    //gets the children folder driveI
    IDriveItemCollectionPage driveChildren= mGraphServiceClient.drives().byId(rootDriveId).root().children().buildRequest().get();
    ArrayList<DriveItem> results = new ArrayList<DriveItem>();
    results.addAll(driveChildren.getCurrentPage());
    return results;
}
```

I realize if getNextPage returns null then there are no more results, but do you have to make another api call to get the next page if there is one?How do I do that with the above setup?

Comment: It looks like `getNextPage` returns a builder, so I would think you'd just do `getNextPage().buildRequest().get()`. Adding this as a comment because I haven't tried so I might be completely wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Brad. I tested at my side and got a success. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IGraphServiceClient client = GetClient();
    IDriveCollectionPage page = client.drives().buildRequest().get();
    List<Drive> drives = page.getCurrentPage();

    while(page.getNextPage() != null){
        page = page.getNextPage().buildRequest().get();
        drives.addAll(page.getCurrentPage());
    }

    System.out.println(drives.size());
}
```